# How to load data bundle in Flutterflow project

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

Is there a demo tutorial on how to Create/add a data bundle for your flutterflow firebase project?
Searching for any demo tutorial for a flutterflow project on creating firestore data bundle.
I am also interested in flutter firebase firestore data bundle setup.
How to load data bundle in Flutterflow project.